Split a pandas dataframe column into multiple based on text in those columns
I have a pandas dataframe with a column.
id    text_col
1     Was it Accurate?: Yes\n\nReasoning: This is a sample text
2     Was it Accurate?: Yes\n\nReasoning: This is a sample text
3     Was it Accurate?: No\n\nReasoning: This is a sample text

I have to break the text_col into two columms "Was it accurate?" and "Reasoning"
The final dataframe should look like:
id    Was it Accurate?    Reasoning
1     Yes             This is a sample text
2     Yes             This is a sample text
3     No              This is a sample text

I tried splitting the text_col using "\n\nReasoning:" but did'nt get desired result.
df[['Was it Accurate?','Reasoning']] = df['text_col'].str.split("\n\nReasoning:")

Are your sentences always Was it Accurate?: XXX\n\nReasoning: YYY?

Assuming a fixed sentence, you could use str.extract with placeholders:
df[['Was it Accurate?', 'Reasoning']] = df['text_col'].str.extract(r'Was it Accurate\?: (Yes|No)\n\nReasoning: (.*)')

Output:
   id                                                   text_col Was it Accurate?              Reasoning
0   1  Was it Accurate?: Yes\n\nReasoning: This is a sample text              Yes  This is a sample text
1   2  Was it Accurate?: Yes\n\nReasoning: This is a sample text              Yes  This is a sample text
2   3   Was it Accurate?: No\n\nReasoning: This is a sample text               No  This is a sample text

regex demo #1
If you want a more generic approach to automatically define the column names, you could use str.extractall and pivot:
out = (df['text_col'].str.extractall(r'([^\n:]+): *([^\n:]+)')
       .droplevel(1).pivot(columns=0, values=1)
      )

NB. this is assuming that the keys ("Reasoning"/"Was it Accurate?") are always unique within a string, if you you'll need an extra step.
Output:
               Reasoning Was it Accurate?
0  This is a sample text              Yes
1  This is a sample text              Yes
2  This is a sample text               No

regex demo #2

I am able to get it splitted, but there are some rows in the 'text_col' which has : in it, so the text beyond that is left out. For ex, "This is a : sample text" if the text is like this, in the output I'm getting only "This is a"

Can you open a follow up question?

I have posted a new question. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78750943/split-a-pandas-dataframe-column-into-multiple-based-on-text-values

@ShubhamR I think my current approach works fine. For the second alternative, slightly change the regex to r'([^\n:]+): *([^\n]+)'. Sorry for getting you to open another question unnecessarily, you might want to delete it.
