Split a pandas dataframe column into multiple based on text values
I have a pandas dataframe with a column.
id    text_col
1     Was it Accurate?: Yes\n\nReasoning: This is a sample : text
2     Was it Accurate?: Yes\n\nReasoning: This is a :sample 2 text
3     Was it Accurate?: No\n\nReasoning: This is a sample: 1. text

I have to break the text_col into two columms "Was it accurate?" and "Reasoning"
The final dataframe should look like:
id    Was it Accurate?    Reasoning
1     Yes             This is a sample : text
2     Yes             This is a :sample 2 text
3     No              This is a sample: 1. text

The text values can have multiple : "colons" in it
I tried splitting the text_col using "\n\nReasoning:" but did'nt get desired result.It is leaving out the text after second colon (:)
df[['Was it Accurate?', 'Reasoning']] = df['text_col'].str.extract(r'Was it Accurate\?: (Yes|No)\n\nReasoning: (.*)')
Edit:

I applied the function on the LLM_response column of my sample_100 dataframe. and printed the first row. if you see closely the sample_100.iloc[0]['Reasoning'] has stripped off all the text after :
Temp dict obj to test on:
{'id_no': [8736215],
 'Notes': [' Temp Notes Sample xxxxxxxxxxxxx [4/21/23, 2:10 PM]  Work started -work complete-'],
 'ProblemDescription': ['Sample problem description xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'],
 'LLM_response': ['Accurate & Understandable: Yes\n\nReasoning: The Technician notes are accurate and understandable as:\n1) The technician provided detailed steps on how they addressed the mold issue by removing materials, treating surfaces, priming, and painting them.\n2) Additionally, even though there was non-repair related information (toilet repairs), the main issue of mold growth was addressed.\n3) The process described logically follows the process for remedying a mold issue, which aligns with the problem description.'],
 'Accurate & Understandable': ['Yes'],
 'Reasoning': ['The Technician notes are accurate and understandable as:']}


It works for me.

Can you provide the output of df.to_dict('list')? This works well for me

try df['text_col'].str.extract(r'Was it Accurate\?: (Yes|No)\\n\\nReasoning: (.*)') : add 1 more backslash for \n

@mozway I have updated the question, please check. added dict object of the output after I ran your answer.

The issue is not due to colons, but to newlines in your sample text. Those are not matched by . by default. You should add the re.DOTALL flag.
Example:
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                   'text_col': ['Was it Accurate?: Yes\n\nReasoning: This is a sample: text',
                                'Was it Accurate?: Yes\n\nReasoning: This is a sample:\n with newline',
                                'Was it Accurate?: No\n\nReasoning: This is a sample text']})

df[['Was it Accurate?', 'Reasoning']] = (df['text_col']
                                         .str.extract(r'Was it Accurate\?: (Yes|No)\n\nReasoning: (.*)',
                                                      flags=re.DOTALL)
                                        )

Output:
   id                                                              text_col Was it Accurate?                         Reasoning
0   1            Was it Accurate?: Yes\n\nReasoning: This is a sample: text              Yes            This is a sample: text
1   2  Was it Accurate?: Yes\n\nReasoning: This is a sample:\n with newline              Yes  This is a sample:\n with newline
2   3              Was it Accurate?: No\n\nReasoning: This is a sample text               No             This is a sample text


one way to handle it could be with the split function.
# deal with the first column by splitting on '\n' and take the first value then split on ':' and take the second one
df['Was it Accurate ?'] = df.apply(lambda x:x.split('\n')[0].split(':')[1],axis=1)
# again split on '\n' then on ':' but put back the ':' if you have many colons in the text. 
df['Reasoning'] = df.apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x.split('\n)[2].split(':')[1:]), axis = 1)

